# EC2: Cannot git clone at launch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, git, github

I am trying to git clone a private repository from GitHub on EC2 instance at launch.

What I have in my script(user data) is the following.

```
git clone -b branchname https://github.com/orgname/reponame.git /var/tmp/reponame
```

For some reason, this ends up

```
Cloning into '/var/tmp/reponame'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

but works fine when executed after launching the instance.
(I have tested it right after the instance launch)

What would be the cause of this error?

Comment: Probably the network is not up yet.

Comment: When SSH is used instead of HTTPS, it works though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say it's a *private repo* - I guess that means it needs a username and password. How are you providing these?

If you have the credentials in e.g. `/root/.git-credentials` (as described [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store)) and `git clone` still doesn't work it may be that **`$HOME` isn't set** in *UserData* script and therefore `git` doesn't find the credentials file.

Two options:

- set `HOME=/root` before running `git clone`, or
- save the `.git-credentials` file to `/`
  (as that's *probably* where is tries to find it when `$HOME` isn't set).

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. `export HOME=/root` did the trick.

Comment: @d-_-b Great :) Care to accept the answer then? Thanks!